# How to cross variables between forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-5.0

I have 2 forms; in form1 there is a slider. How can I get form2's opacity to be set by form1's slider value?

I have already tried: form2.Opacity = form1.trackbar1.value;
but that results in: non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context.

My Guess:
From research, I understand I need to create my second form as a new method/thread? I'm not sure how to pass variables across methods. I've looked through numerous previous posts and I just can quiet find exactly what I need.

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't specify the language or platfrom

Comment: No hatred is necessarily involved. Questions are down-voted when they lack details required to effectively answer them, and / or when it is  clear they could be trivially answered by further research on the part of the asker. It *is* fair to ask for explanation when down-voted, which StressChicken has provided. :)

Comment: @StressChicken please look at the tags. It says "C#"

Comment: That was added after the original down votes

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's C# WinForms, then in the slider change event on form 1

form2.Opacity = form1.trackbar1.value;

Comment: Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Opacity.get

Comment: the code was just meant to point you in the right direction, edit your original answer to include your code and you may get some more help